# How the syntax of the indexOf function works?

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

So the index function will returns the index at which value can be found in the array, or -1 if value is not present in the array, also, it returns the first index that the target can be found at when there are multiple matches.

BUT why set `item === target && result === -1` , this part doesn't make sense? if the given value is in the array is true AND when `result === -1`? we set `result = index` ? what is the purpose of this part......?

BTW we set `var result = -1` for the target that cannot be found in the array is that correct?

```
  _.indexOf = function(array, target){

    var result = -1;

    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
      if (item === target && result === -1) {
        result = index;
      }
    });
    return result;
  };
```

Comment: the `result === -1` inside the `if` just ensures, that the function returns just the first match. After finding the first match in the `each()` callback, `result === -1` will always fail as `result` already has another value.

Comment: that is a bad implementation of indexOf, lets keep looping through everything after we find a match....

Comment: @epascarello can you show me a better way to implement it?

Comment: Bergi's answer already does, but I do not know why you would need to implement it when all modern browsers support indexOf on arrays.

Comment: @epascarello that's right, thanks! just trying to practice how to write higher order functions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you want to set the `result` variable to the current `index` only when two conditions are true:

- the current `item` is the looked-after `target`, and
- the `result` still has the initial value `-1`, i.e. the target has *not already been found*

This way, the `result` will contain the index of the *first* match after the loop.

Btw, this should have been coded without a `result` variable and a `_.each` loop, with a normal `for` loop and an early return it's both faster and easier to understand:

```
_.indexOf = function(array, target) {
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var item = array[i];
        if (item === target) {
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If it didn't test to see if `result` was `-1` then it would return the index of the **last** match instead of the **first** match.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `result === -1` part you will have a different function the returns the index of the last element that is equal to target.